# codeigniter add facebook as registration option

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm working on an online store website with my own registration procedure. users register on my site by selecting a unique username and password along with an email address. now im looking to integrate facebook registration option into my site as well. i have questions about the following:

1. how do i keep the facebook registration process compatible to my existing one. for instance i need the following registration data in either case. if a person clicks the **facebook login** button, how do i capture this additional information? in case the user denies me permission, how do i request it again if needed for some functionality?

   - first and last names
   - registered email address
   - a unique username
   - full date of birth
2. what if a user, who already has a native website registration, also tries to login with facebook? what should be done in this case?

   - should a new account be created and linked to the native account?
   - should the native account be converted into a facebook account?
3. ive tried to hunt for a lot a tutorials with demos but i cant find any good ones. if anyone knows of a good tutorial / demo, please enlighten me. im looking for tutorials / demo that:

   - can be deployed locally for testing.
   - demonstrates native registration + facebook registration
   - built on top of codeigniter.

asim

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you got to create a facebook app, google how to create one, and as long as I perceive I don't think you are allowed to register a user on facebook. Once you create app at facebook, and as per the permission that is provided to the facebook app, once authorized by user, you can extract the details of the user.

For your second answer, you don't have to switch account, create a field for facebook email id so, you have to check for two conditions for login. You can do like "Sign Up with facebook" while user registration.

For codeigniter facebook integration, check the following a3m auth module,

[A3M – A CodeIgniter Account Authentication & Authorization Module Installation](http://blog.biernacki.ca/2010/11/a3m-a-codeigniter-account-authentication-authorization-module-installation/)